# JS - Get and Insert URL

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('clsItemBlock');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');

    iDiv.id = 'detail_button';

    document.getElementsByClassName('clsItemPublished')[i].appendChild(iDiv);

    iDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="###">View Details</a>';
}
```

The code above works and adds a 'View Detail' button to every product on a category page.  What I'm need to now do with this is get the URL from another element and swap out what is currently ### in the example above.

It is essentially the first href inside of the class "clsItemMoreDetails".  I've found chunks of code to do some pieces, but can't seem to piece it all together.

*EDIT*

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="clsItemMoreDetails">
    <a title="Strapless Ruffle Dress" class="onlineUser" href="http://www.runwaycrush.com/women/dresses/strapless-ruffle-dress.html">
        <p class="clsItemHead">Strapless Ruffle Dress</p>
    </a>
    <div class="clsCategorydateBlock clsOverflow">
        <p class="clsItemCategory">
            <a href="http://www.runwaycrush.com/shop/ocean-avenue.html" title="Check out OceanAvenue's store">
                <span>OceanAvenue</span>
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class="clsItemPublished">$68.24
            <span>USD</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer. Lacks important information like HOW the url is related to the button placement.

Comment: How is the code in your question executed and how is the URL retrieved?

Comment: I added a snippet of the html above - hope that helps!

Comment: You reference #clsItemBlock in js fie in the first row - where is it in your snippet?

Comment: This is the contents of it - or a good chunk of it.

Comment: @Topher: from [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) `Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`. If you want to make it easy for others to help you could create a sample on jsfiddle, plnkr. codepen that contains all needed parts - not just a good chunk of it. You code contains `getElementsByClassName('clsItemBlock')` but your html-code lacks it. if it is not needed why include it in the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you should do something like this:

```
var url = document.getElementById("#id_of_some_element").href;
iDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">View Details</a>';
```

Presuming that other element has `href` property.

Comment: Something in this piece is causing it to not show the button:

' + url '

Comment: Updated the answer. Missed a plus sign to the right of the `url`

Comment: I modified it slightly and now it works.  THANK YOU!!!!

var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('clsItemBlock');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'detail_button';
document.getElementsByClassName('clsItemPublished')[i].appendChild(iDiv);
var url = document.getElementsByClassName("onlineUser")[i].href;
iDiv.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">View Details</a>';
 }